# ElasticSearch: Fetch records from nested Array that "only" include given element/s and filter-out the rest with mixed values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I am stuck on one of my tasks.

Overview:

- There are some records on elastic search. Which includes information about the candidates and their employment.
- There is a field that stores information about the statuses in which the candidate got submitted.

```
 {
    "submittedJobs": [
        {
            "status": "PendingPM", "jobId": "ABC", ...
        },
        {
            "status": "PendingClient", "jobId": "XYZ", ...
        },
        {
            "status": "PendingPM", "jobId": "WXY", ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to write an es query to fetch all the records in which submitted jobs array "only" have "pendingPM" statuses and no other statuses.

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "submittedJobs",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "submittedJobs.status.keyword": "PendingPM"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I tried this query, and it returns the records which include "pendingPM" along with other statuses - might use contains() logic.

here is the mapping

```
"submittedJobs": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "statusId": {
            "type": "long"
        },
        "status": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
                }
            }
        },
        "jobId": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

For example. let's suppose there are two documents

```
document #1:
{
    "submittedJobs": [
        {
            "status": "PendingPM", "jobId": "ABC", ...
        },
        {
            "status": "PendingClient", "jobId": "XYZ", ...
        },
        {
            "status": "PendingPM", "jobId": "WXY", ...
        },
        ...
    ]
},

document #2:
{
    "submittedJobs": [
        {
            "status": "PendingPM", "jobId": "ABC", ...
        },
        {
            "status": "PendingPM", "jobId": "WXY", ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Only document #2 should be returned, as the entire array contains only "PendingPM" and no other statuses.

Document #1 will be filtered-out since it includes mixed statuses.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you please put index mapping as well ? what is type of `submittedJobs` field ? is it `object` or `nested` ?

Comment: @SagarPatel added to the description

Comment: You can use inner hits as answer by ESCoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Will be return only document with all item of array with status PendingPM.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "submittedJobs",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "submittedJobs.status": {
                        "query": "PendingPM"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "submittedJobs.status": {
                        "query": "PendingClient"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing @rabbitbr I am getting the relevant results. Thanks a lot. Just one more thing what if I want to have multiple statuses to check. 

i.e. if I want a resultset that only contains "PendingPM", "PendingClient" etc.

Comment: Great!! So, only you add new criteria in must_not. I updated answer.

Comment: Hey @rabbitbr. Thanks for the help. I appreciated it. 

One last thing. What if I want to add another condition in the above query. i.e. If any other statuses except "PendingPM" and "PendingClient" are present in the array then check that it must be at least 90 days old.

let's assume there is a field in the array statusDate. so any statuses other than "PendingPM" and "PendingClient" must be 90 days old.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inner_hits along with nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html) to get only the matched results from the document

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "submittedJobs": {
                "type": "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "submittedJobs",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "submittedJobs.status.keyword": "PendingPM"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "inner_hits": {}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result would be:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "73062439",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "submittedJobs": [
                        {
                            "status": "PendingPM",
                            "jobId": "ABC"
                        },
                        {
                            "status": "PendingClient",
                            "jobId": "XYZ"
                        },
                        {
                            "status": "PendingPM",
                            "jobId": "WXY"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inner_hits": {                         // note this
                    "submittedJobs": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 0.4700036,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "73062439",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "submittedJobs",
                                        "offset": 0
                                    },
                                    "_score": 0.4700036,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "jobId": "ABC",
                                        "status": "PendingPM"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_index": "73062439",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "submittedJobs",
                                        "offset": 2
                                    },
                                    "_score": 0.4700036,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "jobId": "WXY",
                                        "status": "PendingPM"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply @ESCoder. It's still returning mixed results. I added this to the query. 

 "inner_hits": {
              "_source": false,
              "docvalue_fields": [
                "submittedJobs.status.keyword"
              ]
            }

Comment: @MurtazaMultan I have added a working example above in the answer, using the same sample index data. You can see in the search response **inside `inner_hits`. you will get only the matched results**. Let me know if still you are facing the issue.

Comment: oh let me explore a little bit more

Comment: Ah, now I got it. this is like selecting sub-fields from the result set. But I think I was not able to demonstrate my problem.

I want to filter out all the records that have mixed results. I just wanted the records that only contain PendingPM in the entire array. @ESCoder

Comment: I have added the example to the description for better understanding